# How to bubblesort a pointers in the array without changing order of the array

Tags: c++, sorting, pointers

So say I have two arrays  intdataArray[10] = {61 34 46 114 73 29 13 93} and int *pointerDataArray[10] which has the pointers of the dataArray in the same respective index. How would I be able to sort the array through pointers and get the sorted array but also while still being able to print the original array.

My bubble sort is working but it is also changing dataArray as well.

This is the wanted output(correct)

> dataArray before sort: 61 34 46 114 73 29 13 93
> pointerArray before sort: 61 34 46 114 73 29 13 93
> dataArray after sort: 61 34 46 114 73 29 13 93
> pointerArray after sort: 13 29 34 46 61 73 93 114

This is the output I am getting(wrong)

> dataArray before sort: 61 34 46 114 73 29 13 93
> pointerArray before sort: 61 34 46 114 73 29 13 93
> dataArray after sort: 13 29 34 46 61 73 93 114
> pointerArray after sort: 13 29 34 46 61 73 93 114

Here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int readFile(string filename, int dataArray[10], int *pointerDataArray[10]);
void pointerSort(int dataArray[],int *pointerDataArray[] , int length);
void swapIntPtr(int *p1, int *p2);
void displayDataArray(int dataArray[], int length);
void displayPointerArray(int *pointerDataArray[], int length);

int main() {
    int dataArray[10] = {};
    int *pointerDataArray[10];

    int length = readFile("arrayData.txt", dataArray, pointerDataArray);

    cout << "dataArray before sort: ";
    displayDataArray(dataArray, length);
    cout << "pointerArray before sort: ";
    displayPointerArray(pointerDataArray, length);
    cout << endl;

    pointerSort(dataArray, pointerDataArray, length);

    cout << "dataArray after sort: ";
    displayDataArray(dataArray, length);
    cout << "pointerArray after sort: ";
    displayPointerArray(pointerDataArray, length);

}

int readFile(string filename, int dataArray[10], int *pointerDataArray[10]) {
    ifstream inputFile(filename);
    if (inputFile.is_open()) {

        int length;
        inputFile >> length;
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            inputFile >> dataArray[i];
            pointerDataArray[i] = &dataArray[i];
        }
        return length;
    }
    return -1;
}

void pointerSort(int dataArray[],int *pointerDataArray[] , int length){
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < length-1; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < length-i-1; j++)
            if (dataArray[j] > dataArray[j+1]) {
                swapIntPtr(&dataArray[j], &dataArray[j + 1]);
            }
}

void swapIntPtr(int *pointer1, int *pointer2) {
    int pSwap = *pointer1;
    *pointer1 = *pointer2;
    *pointer2 = pSwap;
}

void displayDataArray(int dataArray[], int length){
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        cout << dataArray[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

void displayPointerArray(int *pointerDataArray[], int length){
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        cout << *pointerDataArray[i] << " ";
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure that's what you're asking, but it sounds like you'd want to swap the pointers in the pointer array rather than the values in the `int` array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `pointerSort` function, you're calling the `swapIntPtr` function in the addresses of both integers. It actually changes the content behind the pointers, i.e., it swaps the integers. Instead, you want to call swapIntPtr with the address of the pointers and the function needs to change the pointers.

```
void swapIntPtr(int **pointer1, int **pointer2) {
    int* pSwap = *pointer1;
    *pointer1 = *pointer2;
    *pointer2 = pSwap;
}
```

Aso, make sure to change the declaration on top.

Then, you need to change your sort function to run on the pointerDataArray

```
void pointerSort(int dataArray[],int *pointerDataArray[] , int length){
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < length-1; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < length-i-1; j++)
            if (*pointerDataArray[j] > *pointerDataArray[j+1]) {
                swapIntPtr(&pointerDataArray[j], &pointerDataArray[j + 1]);
            }
}
```

The complete code would look like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int readFile(string filename, int dataArray[10], int *pointerDataArray[10]);
void pointerSort(int dataArray[],int *pointerDataArray[] , int length);
void swapIntPtr(int **p1, int **p2);
void displayDataArray(int dataArray[], int length);
void displayPointerArray(int *pointerDataArray[], int length);

int main() {
    int dataArray[10] = {};
    int *pointerDataArray[10];

    int length = readFile("arrayData.txt", dataArray, pointerDataArray);

    cout << "dataArray before sort: ";
    displayDataArray(dataArray, length);
    cout << "pointerArray before sort: ";
    displayPointerArray(pointerDataArray, length);
    cout << endl;

    pointerSort(dataArray, pointerDataArray, length);

    cout << "dataArray after sort: ";
    displayDataArray(dataArray, length);
    cout << "pointerArray after sort: ";
    displayPointerArray(pointerDataArray, length);

}

int readFile(string filename, int dataArray[10], int *pointerDataArray[10]) {
    ifstream inputFile(filename);
    if (inputFile.is_open()) {

        int length;
        inputFile >> length;
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            inputFile >> dataArray[i];
            pointerDataArray[i] = &dataArray[i];
        }
        return length;
    }
    return -1;
}

void pointerSort(int dataArray[],int *pointerDataArray[] , int length){
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < length-1; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < length-i-1; j++)
            if (*pointerDataArray[j] > *pointerDataArray[j+1]) {
                swapIntPtr(&pointerDataArray[j], &pointerDataArray[j + 1]);
            }
}

void swapIntPtr(int **pointer1, int **pointer2) {
    int* pSwap = *pointer1;
    *pointer1 = *pointer2;
    *pointer2 = pSwap;
}

void displayDataArray(int dataArray[], int length){
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        cout << dataArray[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

void displayPointerArray(int *pointerDataArray[], int length){
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        cout << *pointerDataArray[i] << " ";
    }
}
```

Comment: If the solution is working for you, feel free to upvote the answer as well :)